# binding an event in offline.js

Tags: javascript, setinterval, toastr

I'm trying to get [offline.js](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/) working together with [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) alerts.

My limited JS knowledge is holding me back but hoping some can shed some light on this.

What I want to happen
When the connection goes from down to up, I want to display a "re-connected successfully" message in a toast alert.

The Problem
I don't understand how to check for that status in offline.js. The docs mention that it's possible using this:

> Offline.on(event, handler, context) : Bind an event. Events:
>   up: The connection has gone from down to up
>   down: The connection has gone from up to down

the up event does what i want but i can't figure out how to put it in to practice...

Below is really just some psuedocode explaining what i'd like to happen:

```
function checkifbackonline(){
      var backonlinemessage = "re-connected successfully";
      var checkstate = Offline.on(event, handler, context);
      if (checkstate = true) {
        toastr.info(backonlinemessage);
      }
    }
window.setInterval(checkifbackonline, 3000);
```

Can anyone put me on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not attached up event as per the documentation.

```
function checkifbackonline(evt){
    var backonlinemessage = "re-connected successfully";
    toastr.info(backonlinemessage);
}
Offline.on("up", checkifbackonline);
```

when up is triggerd it will call checkifbackonline function. If you want to remove the event binding then call Offline.off("up");

Comment: ah, perfect! thanks, that's all I needed... makes complete sense now of course that I see an example :)