# Ng-file-upload progress bar not working with offlinejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm use ng-file-upload for fileuploading in my home, and the good news is that it's working fine and I'm able to upload files.

The issue is that the progress bar only shows when i disable the offlinejs in index.html. It seems like offlineJS i preventing the progress callback from the post call.

Here is the error messege I get:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function (xhr) {
          if (!xhr || !(xhr instanceof XMLHttpRequest)) return;
          config.__XHR = xhr;
          if (config.xhrFn) config.xhrFn(xhr);
          xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
            e.config = config;
            notifyProgress(getNotifyEvent(e));
          }, false);
          //fix for firefox not firing upload progress end, also IE8-9
          xhr.upload.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
              e.config = config;
              notifyProgress(getNotifyEvent(e));
            }
          }, false);
        }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
    at Error (native)
    at XMLHttpRequest.f.setRequestHeader (http://localhost:3000/lib/js/offline/offline.min.js:2:3272)
```

Comment: Can you show some code? How do you bind Offline.js ? This thread is about binding Toastr and Offline.js, but maybe this will help you out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411422/binding-an-event-in-offline-js/29414374#29414374

Comment: I don't think that will help very much. I have done just like the example in the thread you mentioned: Offline.on('down', function () {
      $rootScope.$emit('Down');
    });
    Offline.on('up', function () {
      $rootScope.$emit('Up');
    });

Comment: Here is a thread about people having the same error: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/issues/98

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed in the latest version of ng-file-upload!